# Adding custom parameters/queries/headers to a Google Cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am basically wondering if I can have an https Google Cloud function execute differently based on what I pass to it as a parameter (like any normal function with parameters). Possibly with a simple query inside the URL or any other method that works.

As an example, taking a look at the basic starter function in any tutorial:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('Hello, World!');
});
```

I would like to do something like:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  let name = req.query;
  res.status(200).send(`Hello, ${name}!`);
});
```

I hope this makes sense. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello since HTTPS Cloud Functions are POST requests, you can pass parameters of any kind in the request body.

**Example:**
Cloud Function:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  let name = req.body.name;
  res.status(200).send(`Hello, {name}!`);
});
```

Client:

```
fetch('https://firebase.url/helloWorld ', {
    method: 'post',
    body: {name: "Name"},
  }).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  });
```

You can use any request method here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You would also need to add '**$**' to interpolate a variable in a JS string: ``res.status(200).send(`Hello, ${name}!`);``

Comment: I tried doing this using Cloud Scheduler, by inserting `{name: "Name"}` into the body of a job there. But this returns undefined then. Any advice on that?

Comment: Eventually you need to add it like that: {"name": "Name"}

Comment: Thanks. Got it now. I also have to parse it to JSON in my code, as it just returns a string.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed it is possible to pass various parameters to your Cloud Function.

Here's a simple **example** for your reference:

**index.js**

```
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  let name = req.body.name || req.query.name;
  res.status(200).send(`Hello ${name}!`);
};
```

I can call it via the **URL** provided for triggering the function, by appending that URL with `/?name=<desired-name>`:

```
https://<function-region>-<project-name>.cloudfunctions.net/<function-name>/?name=Christiaan
```

---

Alternatively, it can also be called using **curl**:

```
curl --data "name=Christiaan" https://<functions-region>-<project-name>.cloudfunctions.net/<function-name>
```

**Output**:

```
Hello Christiaan!
```

Comment: This answer is better explained. Thank you.